# Reconhecimento de voz com pocketsphinx - Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, reconhecimento-de-voz

Eu estou fazendo reconhecimento de voz com os módulos pocketsphinx e speech recognition, mas quando fui tornar o código disponível off-line, o programa retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anonm\Desktop\Pastas\Programação\Jarvis\main.py", line 55, in <module>
    decoder = pocketsphinx.Decoder(config)
  File "C:\Users\anonm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pocketsphinx\pocketsphinx.py", line 272, in __init__
    this = _pocketsphinx.new_Decoder(*args)
RuntimeError: new_Decoder returned -1
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver este problema? Eis o código:

```py
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
from chatterbot import ChatBot
import os
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
from pocketsphinx import Pocketsphinx, Jsgf, FsgModel

speaker=pyttsx3.init()

bot=ChatBot('Jarvis', read_only=True)


def speak(text):
    speaker.say(text)
    speaker.runAndWait()

config = Pocketsphinx.Decoder.default_config()
config.set_string("-hmm", 'model')  
config.set_string("-lm", 'model.lm.bin')
config.set_string("-dict", 'model.dic')
config.set_string("-logfn", os.devnull)  
decoder = Pocketsphinx.Decoder(config) 

def recognize_pt(audio):
    raw_data = audio.get_raw_data(convert_rate=16000, convert_width=2)
    decoder.start_utt() 
    decoder.process_raw(raw_data, False, True)
    decoder.end_utt() 

    hypothesis = decoder.hyp()
    if hypothesis is not None: 
        return hypothesis.hypstr
    return None

r=sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as s:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(s)

    while True:

        try:
            audio=r.listen(s)

            speech=recognize_pt(audio)

            print('Você disse: ', speech)

            response=bot.get_response(speech)
            print('Bot: ', response)
            speak(response)

        except:
            print('Ocorreu algum erro')
```

Comment: `from pocketsphinx import Pocketsphinx, Jsgf, FsgModel` troca o 'p' minusculo por 'P' maiúsculo

Comment: Agora ele retorna o seguinte erro: "ImportError: No module named 'Pocketsphinx'"

Comment: Na mesma linha de antes? O jeito que te passei é o mesmo que tá na documentação

Comment: Desculpe, não tinha lido sua alteração, alterei o 'p' do pocketsphinx que está logo a frente do 'from', agora ele retorna: "config = pocketsphinx.Decoder.default_config()
NameError: name 'pocketsphinx' is not defined"

Comment: Acho que é a mesma questão, você está importando o módulo Pocketsphinx, então se quer usar ele, tem que ser o maiúsculo, não o minusculo que é a biblioteca.

Comment: No mesmo bloco do erro, alterei todos os 'pocketsphinx' colocando o 'p' inicial maiúsculo, e agora ele já retorna outro erro -estou quase desistindo-: config = Pocketsphinx.Decoder.default_config()
AttributeError: type object 'Pocketsphinx' has no attribute 'Decoder'

Comment: edita a pergunta e coloca o código que você alterou

Comment: tbm estou com esse erro alguem pode explicar o erro?